# PHP 5.4 + WINDOWS + MEMCACHE

Tags: windows, php, memcached

Не вдаваясь в подробности... У кого-нибудь работает данная связка? А то че-то уже весь день пытаюсь заставить ее работать, ничего не получается. Какие только dll не перебрал. Их в инете пруд пруди, но ни одна почему-то не работает. PHP кричит: **Fatal error:** Class 'Memcache' not found in **{filename}** 
Он как-бы это расширение php_memcache.dll вообще не загружает почему-то. Вот...

Уже даже [по этому мануалу](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild) пытался перекомпилировать PHP из исходников с поддержкой этого расширения MEMCACHE. Так там свои ошибки вылазят. Например такая как:

```
pecl\memcache\memcache.c(2250) : error C2198: zend_list_insert: слишком мало арг
ументов для вызова
```

Это единственная ошибка при компиляции memcache 3.0.6.

Заранее спасибо.

**Добавлено:**
Короче, ребят... Забил я на это дело... Не стоит php 5.4 этих мучений. Поставил 5.3 и дело с концом. Вопрос конечно, остается открытым, и я буду бесконечно признателен, если кто знает как его решить. Вообщем, если у кого в будущем возникнут проблемы с этим, то вот чем пользовался я:

PHP 5.3 (5.3.10) (http://windows.php.net/download/)

php_memcache.dll (http://downloads.php.net/pierre/) - для версии 5.3

memcached 1.2.6 (win32 binary - http://code.jellycan.com/memcached/)

**UPD 3.** Че-то за невозможностью написать в другом месте, напишу тут)) Вообщем скомпилировал я PHP. Теперь буду свои расширения писать))) Шучу) Спасибо, Ilya Pirogov, еще раз. Вы очень помогли. ПРоблема,  была в том что я забыл, как вы и сказали, про пункт 12, т.е. про папку deps. Разархивировал [этот архив](http://windows.php.net/downloads/php-sdk/deps-5.4-vc9-x86.7z) туда и все пошло на ура. Я бы выложил свой PHP скомпилированный с memcache, только я смотрю Вы это уже сделали. Кстати, вот что странно... Использовал VC2008 и windows sdk 6.1 при компиляции. Не знаю почему у вас не получилось. Да... И вот какую я configure использовал если кому интересно:

```
--enable-cli-win32 --enable-memcache=shared --enable-snapshot-build
```

Кстати, скомпилированный PHP получился уже 5.4.1RC1-dev :)

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov Нет,нет... На скрине вы видите php 5.4 скачанный когда-то с их сайта, уже собранный. Я просто с моей сборки выдернул файл php_memcache.dll и засунул его в папку /ext этого php rc2. Потому что собрать php вместе со всеми dll-ками у меня не получилось. У меня вот что в папке release_ts лежит после сборки: http://savepic.net/2561505.htm. Я компилировал с параметрами: configure --enable-cli --enable-memcache=shared . Вот я вижу в вашей сборки есть много библиотек, которые моей даже и не снились)) Хотя опять же файлика php5apache2_2.dll нет. Я знаю это я где-то косячу, только вот где

Comment: > Я просто с моей сборки выдернул файл php_memcache.dll и засунул его в папку /ext этого php rc2.

Ну так подсуньте его релизной версии с сайта. 

Вообще, `configure --help` выдает полную справку по всем параметрам. Почитайте, скорее всего вам нужен параметр `--enable-apache2-2hadler`

Comment: Я просто еще не скачивал релизную сборку) Щас наверное скачаю пока суть да дело... Я вот смотрю в вашей сборке есть файлы типа iculx42.dll icule42 libenchant_myspell.dll и т.д. Эти же файлы есть и в оригинальной сборки php. А у меня из всех этих файлов есть только php5ts.dll. Вообщем не знаю... Может я че-то еще забываю сделать? Может после nmake еще нужно что-то сделать? Компилирую то я с теми же параметрами что и у вас...

Comment: Добавьте параметр `--enbale-snapshot-build`, он, по идеи, должен принудительно включить (по возможности как shared) в сборку *все* возможные библиотеки и SAPI.

Comment: да блин... вроде компилируется нормально все... только библиотеки он эти пропускает все равно. А насчет apache говорит не найден файл httpd.h, не буду его компилировать.... но расширения новые добавил в сборку... кстати... возможно что и других файлов типа httpd.h нет, поэтому у меня то и неполная сборка получается....

Comment: Понятно. Вы, видимо, забыли выполнить пункт №12:

> 12. in the same directory (C:\php-sdk\php53dev\vc9\x86) there is a “deps” folder, extract any of your required libraries inside that folder (see http://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/libs) but make sure their top-level contains /include and /lib (some of them have an extra directory level in there)

А именно, распаковать файл [deps-5.4-vc9-x86.7z](http://windows.php.net/downloads/php-sdk/deps-5.4-vc9-x86.7z) в C:\php-sdk\php53dev\vc9\x86

Comment: Странно... Я вот щас смотрю выполнение команды configure. И вижу что она многих библиотек найти не может (.lib файлов). Вот допустим лог: Checking for library libiconv_a.lib ... <not found> libiconv.lib ... <not found> iconv_a.lib ... <not found> iconv.lib ... <not found> libcurl_a.lib;libcurl.lib ... <not found> libbz2_a.lib;libbz2.lib ... <not found>. И так далее.. Чтоб memcache собрать я уже zlib.lib отдельно файл скачал. Ну а где все остальные брать файлы такие? Неужели также по отдельности скачивать?

Comment: Отредактировал предыдущий коммент и ответ :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Расширения работают только с конкретной версией PHP API, по этому бесполезно пытаться запускать memcache.dll от PHP 5.3 на PHP 5.4.

Кроме того, PHP 5.4 только-только вышел и, вполне возможно, что часть pecl расширений не совместимы с ним и банально не будут собираться. Т.ч. нужно просто подождать пока расширения допилят.

**UPD.** Скомпилировалось с memcache версией из svn trunk. Правда только как статическое расширение, как shared library не захотел компилироваться.

[PHP 5.4 Windows x86 VC9 + memcache](http://stalk.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/php-5.4.0-Win32-VC9-x86.zip)

**UPD 2.** Полноценно удалось скомпилировать только с Visual C++ 10 и Winsows SDK 7.1

[PHP 5.4 Windows x86 VC10](http://stalk.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/php-5.4.0-Win32-VC10-x86.zip)

[Memcache Extension](http://stalk.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pecl-5.4.0-Win32-VC10-x86.zip)

И, для кучи, [результыты юнит тестов](http://stalk.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/test.log).

```
=====================================================================
TEST RESULT SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Exts skipped    :   45
Exts tested     :   33
---------------------------------------------------------------------

Number of tests : 11951              8106
Tests skipped   : 3845 ( 32.2%) --------
Tests warned    :    0 (  0.0%) (  0.0%)
Tests failed    :   52 (  0.4%) (  0.6%)
Expected fail   :   35 (  0.3%) (  0.4%)
Tests passed    : 8019 ( 67.1%) ( 98.9%)
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Time taken      :  756 seconds
=====================================================================
```

Comment: СПАСИБО! СПАСИБО!!! СПАСИБО ЗА ОТВЕТ!!! Я так и думал, что это именно из-за того что php еще сырой. Слушайте, если вам не трудно можете ссылочку дать на эту svn'овскую версию? А то как-то я искал svn их не смог найти. Там еще наверное логин нужно получить или как?

Comment: Кстати вы какую версию memcache брали для компиляции? 3.0.6?

Comment: Это сборка из svn, т.е. по сути ночная сборка, у нее еще нет версии. 

Репозиторий находится по адресу http://svn.php.net/repository/pecl/memcache/trunk, checkout можно сделать и без авторизации.

В браузере исходники просмотреть их можно [тут](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/memcache/trunk/). Кстати, последний коммит в memcache.c как-раз сопровождался коментарием "PHP 5.4 compatibility"

Comment: огромное спасибо... еще раз...

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov извините еще раз... У меня вроде получилось скомпилировать memcache как динамическую библиотеку. Вот скрин: http://savepic.net/2571664.htm. Только вот я пока не знаю как получить примерно то что получили Вы? Т.е. php уже сразу готовый к подключению к apache? Вы не могли бы написать команду configure которую вы использовали для компиляции? Если я правильно выразился... Т.е. какие параметры вы передали компилятору непосредственно перед выполнением make? Захотелось что-то уже окончательно с этим разобраться....

Comment: Я компилировал с параметрами:

    configure --enable-cli --enable-memcache

А зачем вы release candidate собираете, когда уже релиз php 5.4 вышел?

Answer (score 2):

Эти эмуляторы все равно нуждаются в расширении `Memcache`, которое тоже нужно устанавливать. Вы можете попробовать `LiteMemcache` - самый легковесный клиент для `Memcached`, написанный на PHP. Все есть - включая `CAS`-операции. Покрыт юнит-тестами, простой и компактный.

[`LiteMemcache`](https://github.com/ptrofimov/litememcache).

Comment: За работу конечно +1. Только расширение написанное на C++ все равно будет быстрее работать.

Comment: Спасибо. Но это не конкурент для сишных расширений, это альтернатива.

Comment: Причем кроссплатформенная) Даже если бы были только get и set были, уже было бы хорошо. А вы еще cas и икременты прикрутили.